# Fake bold and italics in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

Is there a way to make emacs fake bold and italic styles for fonts that don't have them? Generally, programs will make fake bold and italic styles for fonts by shearing them and increasing stroke width if the font doesn't provide an actual italic or bold style, but emacs doesn't seem to do this by default. If I set the `:slant` property for a face using `:family "Source Code Pro"`, for example, it is just ignored, because Source Code Pro does not provide an actual italic variant.

Comment: I'm not sure about making Emacs fake this, but there is a [prerelease of italic variants for Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro/releases/tag/1.002-it).

Comment: I hadn't heard about this, thanks! I'd still like to find out if there's a general solution, but this is a good solution for now.

Comment: http://irreal.org/blog/?p=2828 You could do a similar approach to this